# Enforcing "Run Tests After Build" for all developers of a solution

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

We want to enforce test settings for "Run Tests After Build"on all developers using our solution. Is there way to enforce this? e.g. checking in some settings file?

Comment: What edition of VS do you use (Professional, Community, Enterprise)?

Comment: Downvoter please comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TFS or other version control system there will many ways to achieve it.
As example for TFS with JetBrains TeamCity: [Pre-Tested Commit](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html)

Answer (score -1):

If this setting is a part of .vssettings file - you can do it using ReSharper + StyleCop. Checkout this [article](http://thomasardal.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-share-visual-studio-settings-within-a-team-or-organization/).

But, unfortunately, it's impossible using default Visual Studio instruments.